# How can you vary an image using msdeploy?

Tags: publish, msdeploy

I have a web application I want to publish to multiple different clients, each with their own logo. I'm using 'publish web' from visual studio to do my deployment.
The only way I can think to change it is to have a setting in web.config which I use to decide which logo to display, but this doesn't seem very nice, not least because I'd have to deploy all the logos to every site.
Is there a correct or just better way to achieve this?

Comment: If you're using a different publish profile for each client, you should be able to (a) put the images in a folder not included in the project (b) add .pubxml code to deploy the client's image file from that folder, renaming it to the common logo image name in the process.  See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in a single deploy without also uploading all your images. However, you can do it with two deploys:

1. Deploy the site while skipping logo.jpg (and optionally your logos folder if it's stored inside the web root)
2. Deploy *just* the file as a different filename:

_

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync ^
             -source:contentPath=path\to\src\images\logos\logo1.jpg ^
             -dest:contentPath=sitename\images\logo.jpg
```